# Hiding an element causes its parent not to receive click

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video

I'm attempting to use the jQuery show() and hide() to respectively show and hide a div that contains a play indicator for an HTML5 video player. I am able to use the parent div (#video) to play and pause the video, but once I hide the div containing the image of the play icon (#play) the click function no longer responds making me unable to pause the video.

Any ideas?

I have the follow javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var currentVideo = $('video').get(0);
var playIndicator = $('#play');

$('#video').click(function() {
    if(currentVideo.paused)
    {
        playIndicator.hide();
        currentVideo.play();
        return false;
    } else {
        currentVideo.pause();
        playIndicator.show();
        return false;
    }
})

});
```

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Video Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="video">
<div id="play"></div>
<video id="remoteVideo" poster="redacted" src="redacted" />
</div><!-- #video -->

</div><!-- #container -->

</body>

</html>
```

This file is intended to be included in an iPad publication, thus the odd viewport, and I've redacted the poster and video file links but both work as expected.

Comment: I would say it's something to do with the fact that the `video` would now take up the entire space (as the parent `#video` would resize itself), absorbing any click events.

Answer (score 0):

why not put the click event on `#play` as `$('#play').click(function() {` ?

Answer (score -3):

I vote trying jquery .on instead

```
$('#video').on('click', function(){

//logic goes here

});
```

Comment: There's no difference between `.click()` and `.on('click')`.  Why should this fix the problem?

Comment: @dude: Looking at the jQuery source, calling `$(..).click(function(){})` uses `on()`, so does `bind`, `live` and `delegate`. In essence to that end, it is much better to use `on` to begin with because if you are not using it, it has to make an extra call and then it uses it anyway. However, using `on` like this is most likely not fixing the issue.

Comment: I would say that it is better to use on, but not "much better".

Comment: @Dan: `bind: function( types, data, fn ) { return this.on( types, null, data, fn );}` Given this is what jQuery does it doesn't matter if it is better, much better or slightly better. Either way you are going to use `on`. The only choice left is to decide if you want to execute it directly or indirectly.

Comment: Agreed.  I agree with you.  I just don't think it will make "much" difference.  That's all.